# DEbian squeeze upgrade PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, debian, version

On Debian (Squeeze), I need to upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5.

I tried those commands :
apt-get update; apt-get install php5;

also adding :

```
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But nothing change, it's still PHP 5.3. Any ideas ?  Thanks

Comment: Edit sources.list first, then update, then apt-cache search, then install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Dotdeb has PHP 5.5 for Debian 6 Squeeze. The latest version I can see is 5.4.

They have PHP 5.5 only for Debian 7 Wheezy.

Comment: but there is still a chance, as squeeze is LTS ..?

Comment: LTS means that you have updates for security issues and some main packages. PHP is not made by Debian team and it's seems that PHP 5.5 is incompatible with Debian 6 for some reason - PHP team most probably won't do anything to port PHP 5.5 for old-stable release of OS.

Comment: Official security support has expired on 31 May 2014, so the current support must be unofficial. So maybe backports?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't think there will be any, as Debian 6 is old and not a lot of people using it.

Comment: PHP is not included in LTS support and even if it was, they would provide only security fixes, not new versions. But you can always try to grab the source deb packages for wheezy from dotdeb and try to compile them on squeeze (but you will need a lot of libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Not many people have squeeze now. Did you try http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=108694?  They advice

`apt-get install php5 -t squeeze-php54 -s`

I would try squeeze-php55, and if it works, then without `-s`

Comment: I'm exactly in the case you mentionned the forum link. I've tried what they advices but it still the same (even if it seems there were some updates)